# Change Mic gain programmatically in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio, audioqueue

I am on OSX 10.8

In my Application I had to change the Mic gain, I am using AudioQueue to capture the buffer, but not getting any pointers to change the Mic gain,

Apple HAL documentation also, but didn't get anything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems, changing Volume gain is not possible on the fly when AudioQueue is running, some how able to add Mic gain in the buffer, posting the code,

```
void AQRecorder::setGain(void *data, int bytes, float gain){
    SInt16 *editBuffer = (SInt16 *)data;

    // loop over every packet

    for (int nb = 0; nb < (bytes / 2); nb++) {

        // we check if the gain has been modified to save resoures
        if (gain != 0) {
            // we need more accuracy in our calculation so we calculate with doubles
            double gainSample = ((double)editBuffer[nb]) / 32767.0;

            /*
             at this point we multiply with our gain factor
             we dont make a addition to prevent generation of sound where no sound is.

             no noise
             0*10=0

             noise if zero
             0+10=10
             */
            gainSample *= gain;

            /**
             our signal range cant be higher or lesser -1.0/1.0
             we prevent that the signal got outside our range
             */
            gainSample = (gainSample < -1.0) ? -1.0 : (gainSample > 1.0) ? 1.0 : gainSample;

            /*
             This thing here is a little helper to shape our incoming wave.
             The sound gets pretty warm and better and the noise is reduced a lot.
             Feel free to outcomment this line and here again.

             You can see here what happens here http://silentmatt.com/javascript-function-plotter/
             Copy this to the command line and hit enter: plot y=(1.5*x)-0.5*x*x*x
             */

            gainSample = (1.5 * gainSample) - 0.5 * gainSample * gainSample * gainSample;

            // multiply the new signal back to short
            gainSample = gainSample * 32767.0;

            // write calculate sample back to the buffer
            editBuffer[nb] = (SInt16)gainSample;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember this function should be called only when there is a gain change, otherwise save the CPU resources..

Answer (score 0):

First, ask your queue for its `kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentDevice`, which is the identifier string of the device it's reading from.

Next, you need to open that device. This is more work than it ought to be because Core Audio's designers believe in doing damn near everything through generic “GetProperty” and “SetProperty” functions. Here goes:

1. Create an `AudioValueTranslation` structure containing a pointer to your variable containing the device identifier and a pointer to the variable in which you want the `AudioDeviceID`.
2. Use `AudioHardwareGetProperty` or the not-deprecated but even more generic `AudioObjectGetProperty` to get `kAudioHardwarePropertyDeviceForUID`, passing the pointer to the structure. The HAL will look up the device and return that to you through the pointer you put in the structure.

If that didn't return an error, you now have a device.

The last step is to set its gain. I *think* this is manifested as `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar` on the input scope, but I'm not 100% sure. At any rate, you'll be tinkering with `AudioDeviceSetProperty` and/or `AudioObjectSetProperty` until you find the right combination.

Comment: i tried, but i am not able AudioObjectHasProperty always returns error for mic, moreover, i need to do it When AudioQueue is running :(, got some workaround posting here...